# chmod 600 fails silently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

Here is what happens:

```
$ chmod 600 foobar.txt
$ ls -l
total 1
-rwx------ 0 sampablokuper sampablokuper 13 Feb 19 21:00 foobar.txt
```

Why is the last line not reading as follows?

```
-rw------- 0 sampablokuper sampablokuper 13 Feb 19 21:00 foobar.txt
```

N.B. This is occurring on a server of which I am not the sysadmin. The server is running Linux kernel "3.8.0-33-generic" under the following OS:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS"
MCS Linux 2013/2014 (x86_64)
VERSION = 2013
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.3 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.3 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Comment: Can you try `chmod 0600`

Comment: @Ketan, same result :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the server was using a file system of type "cifs". This was discovered by running the command `df -T`.

Comment: Almost caught that looking at the second field of your `ls -l` output.