# mv overwrites read-only file without prompting

Tags: shell, mv, coreutils

The [GNU Coreutils manual for `mv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html) says:

> If a destination file exists but is normally unwritable, standard
>   input is a terminal, and the -f or --force option is not given, mv
>   prompts the user for whether to replace the file. (You might own the
>   file, or have write permission on its directory.) If the response is
>   not affirmative, the file is skipped.

However, the version of `mv` I am using (GNU coreutils 8.21 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) exhibits unexpected behaviour:

```
$ which mv
/bin/mv
$ ls -l
total 0
$ echo foo > 1; chmod -w 1; cp 1 2; ls -l | cut -d' ' -f 1-5,9
-r-x------ 1 me me 4 1
-r-x------ 1 me me 4 2
$ echo bar > 2
-bash: 2: Permission denied
$ mv 1 2
$ ls -l | cut -d' ' -f 1-5,9
-r-x------ 1 me me 4 2
```

Based upon the manual excerpt quoted above, I would have expected the `mv 1 2` command to have prompted the user before overwriting file `2`.

Is there a bug in my version of `mv`, or a bug in my understanding? If the latter, then what *does* the manual mean?

Comment: Somewhat related: [What is the point of mv -f](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236659/6860)

Comment: Can't reproduce. What does `ls -l /proc/self/fd/0` output?

Comment: Are you `root`? Is the file writable to you by some other means like ACLs (`[ -w 2 ] && echo yes` outputs `yes`)?

Comment: You don't have an alias on `mv`? Are you sure you're running `/bin/mv` ?

Comment: Thanks. Your various helpful comments reminded me: I've been burned by unexpected behaviour, related to permissions, on this particular server [once before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115990/6860).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, the server was using a file system of type "cifs" (presumably the [Common Internet File System, aka CIFS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939973.aspx)). This was discovered by running the command `df -T`.

CIFS apparently exhibits unconventional behaviour with respect to permissions.

Running the same commands on a machine with an ext4 file system and a recent version of Coreutils yielded:

```
$ mv 1 2
mv: replace ‘2’, overriding mode 0444 (r--r--r--)?
```

as expected.

Comment: Interesting. If you do `strace -e access mv 1 2` on the CIFS filesystem, what is the return value that it shows for `access("2", W_OK)` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, that return value is `0`.